# Eager Few Shot Object Detection on Muliti-class Data Prepatation and Visualization

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

I followed this [instruction](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) which is helpful on object detection and took hours to try to make muli-class tuning. It said

> it should be straightforward to extend this to handle multiple classes.

But failed. Thanks for any help!

**Data Prepratation**:

```
# By convention, our non-background classes start counting at 1.  Given
# that we will be predicting just one class, we will therefore assign it a
# `class id` of 1.
duck_class_id = 1
num_classes = 1

category_index = {duck_class_id: {'id': duck_class_id, 'name': 'rubber_ducky'}}

# Convert class labels to one-hot; convert everything to tensors.
# The `label_id_offset` here shifts all classes by a certain number of indices;
# we do this here so that the model receives one-hot labels where non-background
# classes start counting at the zeroth index.  This is ordinarily just handled
# automatically in our training binaries, but we need to reproduce it here.
label_id_offset = 1
train_image_tensors = []
gt_classes_one_hot_tensors = []
gt_box_tensors = []
for (train_image_np, gt_box_np) in zip(
    train_images_np, gt_boxes):
  train_image_tensors.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(
      train_image_np, dtype=tf.float32), axis=0))
  gt_box_tensors.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(gt_box_np, dtype=tf.float32))
  zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes = tf.convert_to_tensor(
      np.ones(shape=[gt_box_np.shape[0]], dtype=np.int32) - label_id_offset)
  gt_classes_one_hot_tensors.append(tf.one_hot(
      zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes, num_classes))
print('Done prepping data.')
```

I think the problem is **zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes** and if there are three classes and a mapping how to change this line

```
zero_indexed_groundtruth_classes = tf.convert_to_tensor(
      np.ones(shape=[gt_box_np.shape[0]], dtype=np.int32) - label_id_offset)
```

**Data visualization:**

How to change visualization code correspondingly?

```
dummy_scores = np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float32)  # give boxes a score of 100%

plt.figure(figsize=(30, 15))
for idx in range(5):
  plt.subplot(2, 3, idx+1)
  plot_detections(
      train_images_np[idx],
      gt_boxes[idx],
      np.ones(shape=[gt_boxes[idx].shape[0]], dtype=np.int32),
      dummy_scores, category_index)
plt.show()
```

Asssuming

```
category_index = {
    1: {'id': 1, 'name': 'a'},
    2: {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'},
    3: {'id': 2, 'name': 'c'}
}

num_classes = 3
 
and three pictures that No.1 has five boxes as a,b,b,c,c;
                        No.2 has two boxes as a,a; 
                        No.3 has four boxes as a,b,c,a.
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For multiple classes, you can just simply create an array with classes and pass that array to this part of the code

```
for (train_image_np, gt_box_np, gt_class) in zip(train_images_np, gt_boxes, gt_classes):
    train_image_tensors.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.convert_to_tensor(train_image_np, dtype=tf.float32), axis=0))
    gt_box_tensors.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(gt_box_np, dtype=tf.float32))
    
    gt_classes_one_hot_tensors.append(tf.one_hot([gt_class], num_classes))
```

where gt_classes = [1,1,1..., 2,2,2,] depending upon the number of classes. This will help you do multiclass object detection.

You can reach out if you have any further doubts